# sed bash command on php script

Tags: php, bash

I need to delete some lines from my dhcpd.conf file by a simple php script. So I'm trying to use sed command to do that.
On terminal I've tryed to use this command to delete from line 1 to 3 and it works:

```
sed -i '1,3d' pippo.txt
```

The problem is that i can't understand how to use sed passing some php variable for line numers.
I need something like:

```
sed -i '$var1,$var2d' pippo.txt
```

can someone help me with the correct sintax for that command on php pls.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use double quotes to expand the variables and wrap the variables with curly braces.

```
var1=1
var2=2
sed -i "${var1},${var2}d" pippo.txt
```

You can define a variable as `$var2d`. If you need to use the variable `$var2`, followed by letter `d`, then you must use curly braces as in `${var2}d`. However this is not necessary for `$var1` in this case as there is no ambiguity, but it's good to follow as a practice.

Comment: thanks for answer. can't understand why still didn't work. 
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 2;
$output=shell_exec('sed -i "${var1},${var2}" pippo.txt');

Comment: Your outermost quotes are single quotes, hence anything inside wont get expanded. To allow expanding internals, swap single quotes and double quotes. BTW, your `sed` command is anyway wrong. what are you trying to do?? Just to demonstrate, following will duplicate only the first and second lines (without producing any output though).

`$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 2;
$output=shell_exec("sed -i '${var1},${var2}p' pippo.txt");`

Comment: what i need to do is to delete some lines from a file. for example i need to delete from line 2 to line 5 on file by sed command by a php script. it's works when i try to use sed command from terminal specifying the line but when i try to do that with php variable on my script script doesn't work. no line was deleted.